# How to Un-link the Js File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to Unlink the JS file Which is included in header,

But i want to unlink that file in one particular file.But the header file is included in every file

Comment: What is the language that you are using `php` or what?

Comment: What you mean by *unlink*. To not take affect.

Comment: Why not just remove the link?

Comment: If you JS is loading after the one you wish to remove this may not work.

Comment: Language is HTML,Guys i just want my page not to include that particular Js file

Comment: @AxiomNeha then how have you separated the file into chunks i.e. header

Comment: HTML is not a language, it is a Technology, @Axiom Neha

Comment: Just the script tag ..actually jquery 1.9 is affecting my code,,andi want to use 1.8 for that particular page

Comment: @AxiomNeha You want to remove the script tag using another script, on some of your pages?

Comment: @KiranRS if you don't know about my query..So you shouldn't post your silly answers

Comment: @Neha Rana - I dont think this is very silly dude. You will know one day.

Comment: yes i just don't want that js in one file @sanjeevmk

Comment: @NehaRana You should frame your question properly. Describe the entire problem. From your comments, it seems you want to selectively include a js file. That is not clear in your question.

Comment: include your HTML as well

Comment: it is very clear ..cant explain more than this ..thank you

Comment: @Neha Rana- Post some codes or explain some more

Answer (score 0):

Create some variable before including the header and then inside the header, and set it to `true` for example and then inside header, check if the value is true then let the script be included otherwise not.

```
::pseudo code::

1. variableAbc = true;
2. include the header file
```

Now inside the header file, do this

```
if variableAbc is true
    include the script
else
    Don't bother including that script
```

**Alternative**

Use jQuery to completely remove that script from the page `$('youScript').remove()`

Comment: Ia m using Expression engine.. so can't put this kind code over there

Comment: $('youScript').remove() ,,,what should i write instead of youScript??

Comment: @AxiomNeha assign some class to the `script` tag, say `removeable` and then `$('.removeable').remove()`

Comment: @NehaRana sorry, I have no experience using `Expression Engine` so I don't know if there is any way to achieve that with this